# VPN, Tunneling to hide 'real IP' through my proxy server while showing the client IP on 'real' server side

Tags: vpn, openvpn, tunneling, ssh-tunnel

I would like to hide my '*main server*' behind the load balancer, call it *'proxy server*'
Although I use some **closed-source software** on '*main server*' and it needs the client IP address to operate well.

When I'm setting up some **VPN** connection, in that software it displays the IP address of my 'proxy server'.

Is there any option to set up such tunneling or vpn to:

1. not reveal IP of '*main server*'
2. show the IP of '*client*' in '*application*' on '*main server*'

I will be grateful for all your replies and ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is all entirely possible using OpenVPN. Based on the tone of your post, it may have a very large learning curve for you. You will need to create iptables rules on your proxy to guide and NAT this traffic. In short, the client will connect to "proxy server." Traffic from "client" to "main server" keeps the client's IP. Return traffic to the "client" from "main server" will have NAT performed to originate from the "proxy server." This way the client is never aware that a "main server" exists.

I'd also like to discourage you from using your (web application?) load balancer as a VPN server. VPNs can generate tons of traffic, and to you this means CPU usage.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
Sure, I'm ready to learn new things, I agree that setting up VPN is pretty new thing for me.
My 'load balancer' machine is intel i5-2500 3.3GHz, dedicated only for being that "gate" and "load balancer" for incoming connections.
Could you point me to some option in OpenVPN which I should master to set up it?

Comment: That should be more than sufficient. Work through this tutorial: http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html Good luck, and come back if you hit any walls.